# NiViewer: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data

Tags: c++, kinect, ubuntu-14.04, openni

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04`. I've installed `OpenNI-1.5` with `Sensor-Bin-Linux-x64-v5.1.2.1`. I have two Kinects connected to my system. When I run `NiViewer`, it shows the video streaming from one of them, but with a warning

```
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
```

[This](http://daybydaylinux.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-compile-openni-and-sensorkinect.html) link says that it should work after changing `UsbInterface=1` (and `sudo ./install.sh`) in the `Sensor-Bin` config, but it didn't.
I've a code which captures point clouds from these Kinects. But that is giving

```
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
iterminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have a code which uses `ARToolKitPlus` to detect marker transformation. That is also giving the same warning. It's detecting the markers but giving zero matrix transformation.

**Note: Everything above was working perfectly when I was working on `ubuntu12.04`. Now, I reinstalled everything to make it work on `14.04`. Earlier, it was `pcl-1.5` but now it's `pcl-1.7`.**

Comment: First of all, I suggest never to upgrade your ubuntu when the libraries you use are not being updated anymore... Also, I suggest to use gdb, to know where exactly this error is happening... maybe it is not even with openni. when you have the line where the error happens show it in your post. Most probably a library that openni depends was upgraded and it doesn't work properly anymore... Also, I think you should show how are initializing the kinects. In my case I have always seen the warning, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: `NiViewer` is included by OpenNI package. This seems to be a common problem (see (here)[http://daybydaylinux.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-compile-openni-and-sensorkinect.html] as mentioned in the question). Most probably, I think this warning is a problem because the program which was working earlier is not working now.

Comment: Are you using an ARM processor? That link is for ARM processors... Again, I think if you post some snippets of code, we can understand what is really happeninng... maybe ome gdb backtrace too

Comment: `NiViewer` comes with the `OpenNI` package itself. It has a `NiViewer` directory in the samples containing many cpp and h files. I'm not sure how it's working.

Comment: How to check if my processor is ARM? What to look in `uname -a`?

Comment: It worked. I can't help with that USB warning. But it was showing error in typecasting somewhere in my code. I still doubt why it was working earlier.

Comment: Yes, that usually happens. I am glad, you cuould solve your problem.

Comment: Are you using the same compiler version as on the 12.04?

Comment: Can I take my bounty back? :P

Comment: I have used as on 12.04 and as on 14.04, and both work and both give the same warning